# Finding Divisors using loops

Tags: c

I wrote the code for the following program but I don't understand how I can involve a  function. The question asks me to use a function that returns the sum of divisors. Please take a look at the question and my code and try to help me out.

THE QUESTION:

> Write a C program that finds and prints the sum of divisors for all
>   the numbers between 101 and 110.  The divisors of x are those numbers
>   x divides without a remainder (e.g. the divisors of number 10 are 1,
>   2, 5, and 10 and their sum = 1+2+5+10=18, the divisors of number 11
>   are 1 and 11 and their sum=1+11=12, and so forth).
>       Your program should also print the number (101 to 110) that has the maximum sum of divisors.
>
> Your program should use at least one function called div_sum that
>   takes a number and returns its sum of divisors.

MY CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()

{
int i=1, x=101, sum, smax=0, xmax=0;

    for (x=101; x<=110; x++)
        {  sum=0;

           for(i=1; i<=x; i++)
               {
                  if(x%i==0)
                  sum+=i;
               }

           if(sum>smax)
               {
                  smax=sum;
                  xmax=x;
               }

           printf("The sum of factors of %d = %d\n",x,sum);

        }

    printf("The number that has the maximum sum of divisors is %d with the sum of %d",xmax,smax);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine, besides that you do not use a function `div_sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the loop where you calculate sum of divisors for each x to separate function:

```
int div_sum(int x) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        sum+=i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and use it in your program:

```
for (x=101; x<=110; x++)
{  
   sum= div_sum(x);
   if(sum > amax)
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For each number in the loop, call the function. The function should have all the code you currently have in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually really close.

Here's what I did:

```
void div_sum()
{        

    int sum;
    int max_sum = 0;
    int max_num;

    for (int x = 101; x <= 110; x++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        if (x%i == 0)
            sum = sum + i;

        printf("\nFor the number %d, the sum of the divisors is %d\n", x, sum);         
        if (sum > max_sum)
        {
            max_sum = sum;
            max_num = x;
        }
    }
    printf("max = %d\n", max_num);
}
```